# how to parse JSON response after i have made a POJO class for JSON response?

Tags: android, json, pojo

This is my POJO class in which i want to parse my JSON.

```
public class TestPojo {
  @SerializedName("Login Response")
  private List<com.example.amans.demoparsing.LoginResponse> mLoginResponse;

  public List<com.example.amans.demoparsing.LoginResponse> getLoginResponse() {
     return mLoginResponse;
  }

  public void setLoginResponse(List<com.example.amans.demoparsing.LoginResponse> LoginResponse) {
    mLoginResponse = LoginResponse;
  }
}
```

Comment: put your json response here

Comment: This is my JSON response "{
    "Login Response": [
      {
        "Status code":"200",
        "OP Status":"0",
        "Status Message":"Data Parsed Successfully",
        "Error Message":"Could not get response",
        "Date and Time":"Friday, 7 April"
      }
    ]
 }
" @Bh

Comment: i think your pojo creation for json response is wrong....try this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for creating pojo class for your json response 
in [Serialized Name] annotation we given the param name @SerializedName("Login Response") in my view this is not an param name (Login Response)

Comment: see by your given json it create pojo like this
   import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("LoginResponse")
@Expose
private List<LoginResponse> loginResponse = null;

public List<LoginResponse> getLoginResponse() {
return loginResponse;
}

public void setLoginResponse(List<LoginResponse> loginResponse) {
this.loginResponse = loginResponse;
}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your pojo like below and add this gradle in your `build.gradle` `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'`

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class TestPojo {

    @SerializedName("Login Response")
    @Expose
    private List<LoginResponse> loginResponse = null;

    public List<LoginResponse> getLoginResponse() {
        return loginResponse;
    }

    public void setLoginResponse(List<LoginResponse> loginResponse) {
        this.loginResponse = loginResponse;
    }


    public class LoginResponse {

        @SerializedName("Status code")
        @Expose
        private String statusCode;
        @SerializedName("OP Status")
        @Expose
        private String oPStatus;
        @SerializedName("Status Message")
        @Expose
        private String statusMessage;
        @SerializedName("Error Message")
        @Expose
        private String errorMessage;
        @SerializedName("Date and Time")
        @Expose
        private String dateAndTime;

        public String getStatusCode() {
            return statusCode;
        }

        public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
            this.statusCode = statusCode;
        }

        public String getOPStatus() {
            return oPStatus;
        }

        public void setOPStatus(String oPStatus) {
            this.oPStatus = oPStatus;
        }

        public String getStatusMessage() {
            return statusMessage;
        }

        public void setStatusMessage(String statusMessage) {
            this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
        }

        public String getErrorMessage() {
            return errorMessage;
        }

        public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
            this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        }

        public String getDateAndTime() {
            return dateAndTime;
        }

        public void setDateAndTime(String dateAndTime) {
            this.dateAndTime = dateAndTime;
        }

    }
}
```

and then use above pojo below like

```
TestPojo testPojo = new Gson().fromJson(response,TestPojo.class);
String statusMessage = testPojo.getLoginResponse.get(0).getStatusMessage();
```

Comment: and then how will I display my response string?

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!! It was really helpfull.

Comment: just one more thing, what does response refer to? do we have to define it?

Comment: are you call login api? in to server

Comment: i am taking response from server, so it is not static. so i cannot define the response string in my code.

Comment: I do not understand your above  "just one more thing, what......" comment

Comment: see i am taking response from the server and in above code you have used  "new Gson().fromJson(response,TestPojo.class);" . In this what is response?? Response cannot be static in my case.

Comment: just add your server response in that case

Comment: which format did you get the response? string or JSON object

Comment: i got the response in JSON object

Answer (score 2):

You need to use GSON class for this

```
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Then in the code where you the response string add this lines for code

```
  String response = // your response string is in array
  List<LoginResponse> list = Arrays.asList(new Gson()
                              .fromJson(response, LoginResponse[].class));
```

OR  you want it on your test pojo class

```
    String response = // your response string
    TestPojo testPojo = new Gson().fromJson(response, TestPojo.class);
```

Happy coding.. :)